# Unity 2D A* Pathfinding Move X axis ONLY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I am new to A* Pathfinding i want to get the enemy ai to move only in x axis. How can i do that? this is what i got right now:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Pathfinding;

public class SimpleZombieAI : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector2 targetPosition;

    public void Start (){
        Seeker seeker = GetComponent<Seeker> ();

        seeker.StartPath (transform.position, targetPosition, OnPathComplete);

    }

    public void OnPathComplete (Path p) {

        Debug.Log ("Yay, we got a path back. Did it have an error? "+p.error);

    }
}
```

but it goes in x and y and i want to make it go ONLY x. I hope someone can help me because i dont know where to post about this question.

Comment: Have you tried using `transform.position.x, targetPosition.x,`? I don't know the method so it might produce errors, but try it.

Comment: yup i tried it and then i get The best overloaded method match for `Seeker.StartPath(Pathfinding.Path, OnPathDelegate, int)' has some invalid arguments and Argument `#1' cannot convert `float' expression to type `Pathfinding.Path' if i fix the argument 1 error it show a error in argument 2 then.

Comment: Moving along a single direction does not seem to require any path planning. After all, there aren't many options if the path is blocked. Please describe what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to make ai to chase the player in x only.

Comment: Then define an acceleration along the x-axis that is proportional to the distance to the player and maybe a maximum velocity and let physics do the rest. No need for path finding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `Seeker.StartPath` function takes `Vector` parameters, so just passing the x values won't work.  While I don't think you would really need to use pathfinding for a one-dimensional path, if that's what you want to use, here's a way that you might be able to achieve that.

```
public void Start (){
    Seeker seeker = GetComponent<Seeker> ();

    float myY = transform.position.y;
    seeker.StartPath (transform.position, new Vector2(targetPosition.x,myY), OnPathComplete);

}
```

This will have your enemies move along their constant y-value line, while chasing from their own x-coordinate to the player's x-coordinate.